# Invalid Date Format while using SQL server Export Wizard

Tags: sql-server, datetime, sql-server-2012, export, invalid-argument

I am trying to Export Data from one SQL Server to another. I have around 12 tables among which 11 was successfully exported however having issue in one table, it has 2 columns as `DateTime` while exporting I am getting this exception :

```
- Copying to [dbo].[ClaimDetails] (Error)
Messages
Error 0xc0202009: Data Flow Task 1: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005.
An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "Invalid date format".
(SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

Error 0xc020901c: Data Flow Task 1: There was an error with Destination -     ClaimDetails.Inputs[Destination Input].Columns[Entrydate] on Destination -   ClaimDetails.Inputs[Destination Input]. The column status returned was:   "Conversion failed because the data value overflowed the specified type.".
(SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

Error 0xc0209029: Data Flow Task 1: SSIS Error Code   DTS_E_INDUCEDTRANSFORMFAILUREONERROR.  The "Destination -  ClaimDetails.Inputs[Destination Input]" failed because error code 0xC020907A  occurred, and the error row disposition on "Destination -  ClaimDetails.Inputs[Destination Input]" specifies failure on error. An error  occurred on the specified object of the specified component.  There may be error  messages posted before this with more information about the failure.
(SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

Error 0xc0047022: Data Flow Task 1: SSIS Error Code  DTS_E_PROCESSINPUTFAILED.  The ProcessInput method on component "Destination -  ClaimDetails" (124) failed with error code 0xC0209029 while processing input  "Destination Input" (137). The identified component returned an error from the  ProcessInput method. The error is specific to the component, but the error is  fatal and will cause the Data Flow task to stop running.  There may be error  messages posted before this with more information about the failure.
(SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

Error 0xc02020c4: Data Flow Task 1: The attempt to add a row to the Data  Flow task buffer failed with error code 0xC0047020.
(SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

Error 0xc0047038: Data Flow Task 1: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PRIMEOUTPUTFAILED.   The PrimeOutput method on Source - ClaimDetails returned error code 0xC02020C4.   The component returned a failure code when the pipeline engine called  PrimeOutput(). The meaning of the failure code is defined by the component, but  the error is fatal and the pipeline stopped executing.  There may be error  messages posted before this with more information about the failure.
 (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)
```

It successfully copies around 4025 rows and i have around 21794 rows, so its a bit difficult to manual look at each row, so i tried running

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
   ClaimDetails
WHERE
    ISDATE(ActualDate) = 0
```

On both fields but it shows no row, so please let me know what I can do.

Date fields format look like this
[image: Date fields format look like this]

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should set dateformat first. Looking at your records it should be **ymd**.

```
    SET DATEFORMAT ymd;

SELECT *
FROM ClaimDetails
WHERE ISDATE(ActualDate) = 0
```

Comment: May be you also need to set date format for destination database.

Comment: i am not coping data through this query, however should I create a Database with same columns with same types and then try to export ?

Comment: Yes, I understood. What I was trying to say keep both source and destination dateformat same. And yes, match the datatype of source and destination columns.

Comment: sorry for delay response , yes you were right destination's datatype was of date and source was datetime so changed and it worked , thanks

Comment: Np... Always WC :)

Answer (score 0):

Sort your table by the date field (oldest to newest). If there are Null values then scroll to the first records that has data. Now make sure that the year is the correct year.